# Recorrer foreach en controlador codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy trabajando en `Codeigniter` y pues estoy haciendo una pequeña validación en el `index` de mi controlador este es el código:

```
function index()
    {
    $user = $this->session->userdata("id");
        $consulta = $this->cliente_model->get_roles_usuario($user);

        foreach ($consulta as $row) {
          if ($row->Url === 'cliente/index'){
        $this->load->view('guest/head');
        $this->load->view('guest/nav');
        $this->load->view('guest/section');
        $this->load->view('cliente/cliente_view');
            }
        }
        redirect(base_url());

    }
```

La consulta funciona bien, ya lo he comprobado, me devuelve lo que deseo que es:

- **Url**
- producto/index
- proveedor/index
- cliente/index

Si dentro de resultado de mi consulta tengo el valor igual del que coloqué en el `if`, en esta caso sí lo es, me tendría que cargar la vista. En caso contrario redireccionarme al inicio de mi aplicación ¿estoy fallando en el `foreach`?

Answer (score 1):

Ademas de lo comentado y como optimizacion, dentro del if deberias poner un continue; para que cuando imprima las vistas que quieres termine de dar vueltas en el foreach (imagina si en vez de 3 resultados fueran miles harias comprobaciones innecesarias). Saludos.

```
foreach ($consulta as $row) {
           //row es un array;
   if ($row['Url'] === 'cliente/index'){
        $this->load->view('guest/head');
        $this->load->view('guest/nav');
        $this->load->view('guest/section');
        $this->load->view('cliente/cliente_view');
        continue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sin ver la implementacion del model y suponiendo que ya has cargado el model en el controller, lo que sucede muy posiblemente es que el model te este devolviendo un array, por lo tanto el código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
function index()
    {
    $user = $this->session->userdata("id");
        $consulta = $this->cliente_model->get_roles_usuario($user);

        foreach ($consulta as $row) {
           //row es un array;
          if ($row['Url'] === 'cliente/index'){
        $this->load->view('guest/head');
        $this->load->view('guest/nav');
        $this->load->view('guest/section');
        $this->load->view('cliente/cliente_view');
            }
        }
        redirect(base_url());

    }
```